# Text change on click for toggling elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to change a '+' into '-' when toggling elements. I've tried a few things but once the symbol changes it won't toggle back and forth like it should. I've searched the other posts but they don't work for my bit of code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
$("trace_dump").hide();

//Slide up and down on hover
$("h3").click(function(){
    $(this).next("trace_dump").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).text($('span').text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
});
});
</script>
```

...and here's the html:

```
<h3><span>+</span>print_r()</h3>
<trace_dump>
    print_r($e);
</trace_dump>
<h3><span>+</span>var_dump()</h3>
<trace_dump>
    var_dump($e);
</trace_dump>
```

Can I get some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
    $(this).text($('span').text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
```

`this` is refering to the h3 and not the `span` like I think you intended.

Try this:

```
$(this).find('span').text($(this).find('span').text()=='+'?'-':'+');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your inline conditional check, you query for all `<span>` elements and compare the `.text()` contents. This obviously won't work. Use `$(this).find('span')` or even better, do it like this:

```
$(this).find('span').text(function(i, text) {
    return text === '+' ? '-' : '+';
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/qR2NU/8/

Comment: Thank you! that's pretty sweet as well.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you need to enclose it in a *div* that supports *show/hide* operations. there is no html tag `trace_dump`</strike>

This works. See demo [here](http://jsbin.com/oveqo6/edit)

**UPDATE:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {             
$("trace_dump").hide();
//Slide up and down on hover
$("h3").click(function(){
    $(this).next("trace_dump").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).find("span").html(($(this).find("span").text().trim() == '+' ? '-' : '+'));  
}); 

});
```

Comment: Nah, the code works just fine. I just need to have the little '+' change from + to - on toggle.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that it works as is. I've used XML style tags. Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/qR2NU/8/ (link via jAndy below)

Answer (score 0):

I think, after the first call to your function, the span element is replaced by + or -
And so from the next call onwards, jquery does not find the span element at all

I haven't tested it, but reading the code makes me believe this.

Maybe remove the span entirely and replace by + or -

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well. If you give the context as the second parameter, then the search is limited to within the enclosing element. In this case its "h3"

```
 var element = $('span',$(this));
    element.text(element.text() == '+' ? '-':'+');
```